# Transport theorem in spacecraft control: tracking a reference angular velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, space, satellites

I am reading the book named "Analytical mechanics aerospaces systems" by Schaub and Junkins.

In section 7.2, the task is to control the spacecraft to track a specified angular velocity $w_r$ specified in reference frame $R$ (my understanding of this statement is $w_r = \sum_{i=1}^3w_{ri}\overrightarrow{r_i}$, correct?).

**My first question is, why the reference angular velocity $w_r$ is given in the R frame? Could someone give an example?**

The angular velocity of the spacecraft is $w$ with respect to the body frame $B$ of the spacecraft (my understanding of this statement is $w = \sum_{i=1}^3w_{bi}\overrightarrow{b_i}$, correct?).

So the reference tracking error
is $\delta{w}=w-w_r = \sum_{i=1}^3w_{bi}\overrightarrow{b_i}- \sum_{i=1}^3w_{ri}\overrightarrow{r_i}$, correct?  Note both the base vector $b_i$ and $r_i$ can be represented in the inertial frame.

when this vector is represented in the Body frame $B$,  we have
$${}^{B}\delta{w}={}^{B}w-[BR]{}^{R}w_r,$$ where $[BR]$ is the transformation matrix from R frame to B frame and the left superscript means the reference frame.
(it is better to specify between which two frames an angular velocity is defined)

Now the transport theorem in Equation (1.21) of the book is written as
$${}^N{d/dt({}^B{\overrightarrow{p}})}={}^Bd/dt({}^B{\overrightarrow{p}}) + {}^B{w}\times {}^B{\overrightarrow{p}} (1.21) $$ where $\overrightarrow{p}$ is a vector in the body frame $B$, $\times$ means cross product, $N$ means inertial frame.

If we replace $\overrightarrow{p}$ with ${}^Bw$ in (1.21), we get
$${}^N{d/dt({}^B{w})}={}^Bd/dt({}^B{w}) + {}^B{w}\times {}^B{w} = {}^Bd/dt({}^B{w}) (4.30)$$ which is equation (4.30) in the book.

Now we ultimately want the expression for $d/dt \delta{w}$ in the B frame,  the book wrote
$${}^B d/dt (\delta{w}) = \dot{w} -\dot{w_r} + w\times w_r (7.35)$$ which is equation (7.35) in the book, where the book use overhead dot to denote the derivative with respect to the inertia frame $N$ as a shorthand.

**My second question is, how this is derived?**

I made the following derivation

$${}^B d/dt ({}^B w - {}^Bw_r) = \dot{w} - {}^B d/dt{}^Bw_r,$$ since we have equation (4.30) derived above, which says the rate of change of angular velocity w.r.t. the body frame and inertia frame is the same.

Now the task is to derive ${}^B{d/dt({}^B{w_r})} = \dot{w_r} - w\times w_r$ in order to lead to Equation (7.35)

Note $w_r$ should be the angular velocity of R w.r.t. N, if I understand correctly?
and $w$ should be the angular velocity of B w.r.t. N, right?

**My third question is , why the matrix [BR]does not occur?**

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question, i.e.
derive ${}^B{d/dt({}^B{w_r})} = \dot{w_r} - w\times w_r$ in order to lead to Equation (7.35),  I make more rigorous notations here.

i.e.
derive ${}^B{d/dt({}^{R/N}_B{w_r})} = \dot{w_r} - {}^{B/N}_Bw\times {}^{R/N}_Bw_r$, where the left superscript means the definition of angular velocity, for example $B/N$ means body frame w.r.t. inertia frame.

Now use transport theorem,

$${}^N{d/dt({}^{R/N}_B{w_r})} = {}^B{d/dt({}^{R/N}_B{w_r})} + {}^{B/N}_Bw\times {}^{R/N}_Bw_r$$,
if we define the l.h.s. to be $\dot{w_r}$, then by moving terms around, we get the conclusion.  but still, the right conclusion should be
${}^N{d/dt({}^{R/N}_B{w_r})} = {}^N{d/dt([BR]{}^{R/N}_R{w_r})}$, RIGHT?
but what is the expression for ${}^N{d/dt([BR]{}^{R/N}_R{w_r})}$ then?

it seems to be $[{}^{B/R}_N\tilde{w}][BR]{}^{R/N}_R{w_r} + [BR]{}^N d/dt{}^{R/N}_R{w_r}$ where $[{}^{B/R}_N\tilde{w}]$ is the skew symmetric matrix of ${}^{B/R}_N w$